# Strange Spacing in First of Multiple TikZ Nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, spacing

I want to create a simple diagram using TikZ. The code below shows an issue that I cannot solve: The first node has a different spacing between the second and the third cell (between the words "some condition" and the `itemize` list) compared to all other nodes. Note that the *first node* refers to the one first defined in the code which is called *State 2*, not the one on top of the picture which is called *State 1*. I added lines to the tabular to better illustrate the issue at the "Some Text" part.

It seems adding more space to `topsep` of the `itemize` has a negative effect and adding the `below=of orig` part (see commented lines) to force the same syntax does not change anything. What can I do to have the first node look exactly like the others?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[!h]
\centering

\tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex', color=black}}
\tikzset{newbox/.style={rounded corners=1.75pt, very thick, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=brown!90!black}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.0cm and 0.7cm, auto]
    %\coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
    %\node [newbox, below=of orig] (s2) {
    \node [newbox] (s2) {
        \begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\color{red}{\textsc{State 2}}}\\\hline
        {some condition:}\\\hline
        \parbox{5.6cm}{
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep,topsep=5pt]
            \item Some Text
            \item Some More Text Here
            \end{itemize}
        }\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    };
    \node [newbox, right=of s2] (s3) {
        \begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\color{red}{\textsc{State 3}}}\\\hline
        {some condition:}\\\hline
        \parbox{5.6cm}{
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep,topsep=5pt]
            \item Some Text
            \item Some More Text Here
            \end{itemize}
        }\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    };

    \coordinate (mid) at ($(s2.north east)!0.5!(s3.north west)$);

    \node [newbox, above=of mid] (s1) {
        \begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\color{red}{\textsc{State 1}}}\\\hline
        {some condition:}\\\hline
        \parbox{5.6cm}{
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep,topsep=5pt]
            \item Some Text
            \item Some More Text Here
            \end{itemize}
        }\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    };

    \draw [line] (s1) -- (s2);
    \draw [line] (s2) --++ (s3);
    \draw [line] (s3) to [min distance=50pt,out=15,in=30,looseness=1] node[above] {otherwise} (s3);
    \draw [line] (s3) to [loop above,looseness=4] node[above] {otherwise} (s3);
    \draw [line] (s3.south) --++ (0cm,-0.5cm) -| (s2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{MWE}
\label{fig:mwe}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could just use `p{5.6cm}` rather than `l` in the tabular spec and dispense with the `\parbox`. However, that's off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hack:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[!h]
  \centering
  \mbox{}
  \par
  \tikzset{%
    line/.style={draw, thick, -latex', color=black},
    newbox/.style={rounded corners=1.75pt, very thick, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=brown!90!black},
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.0cm and 0.7cm, auto]
    \node [newbox] (s2) {
      \begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\color{red}{\textsc{State 2}}}\\\hline
        {some condition:}\\\hline
        \parbox{5.6cm}{
          \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep,topsep=5pt]
            \item Some Text
            \item Some More Text Here
          \end{itemize}
        }\\\hline
      \end{tabular}
    };
    \node [newbox, right=of s2] (s3) {
      \begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\color{red}{\textsc{State 3}}}\\\hline
        {some condition:}\\\hline
        \parbox{5.6cm}{
          \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep,topsep=5pt]
            \item Some Text
            \item Some More Text Here
          \end{itemize}
        }\\\hline
      \end{tabular}
    };

    \coordinate (mid) at ($(s2.north east)!0.5!(s3.north west)$);

    \node [newbox, above=40pt of mid] (s1) {
      \begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\color{red}{\textsc{State 1}}}\\\hline
        {some condition:}\\\hline
        \parbox{5.6cm}{
          \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep,topsep=5pt]
            \item Some Text
            \item Some More Text Here
          \end{itemize}
        }\\\hline
      \end{tabular}
    };

    \draw [line] (s1) -- (s2);
    \draw [line] (s2) --++ (s3);
    \draw [line] (s3) to [min distance=50pt,out=15,in=30,looseness=1] node[above] {otherwise} (s3);
    \draw [line] (s3) to [loop above,looseness=4] node[above] {otherwise} (s3);
    \draw [line] (s3.south) --++ (0cm,-0.5cm) -| (s2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{MWE}
  \label{fig:mwe}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: more space]